# csrf issue with yii2 on server

Tags: php, apache, yii2, csrf

I have a problem making forms of yii2 work on a server. I have the project on my local machine and it is working fine, but on the server (which is supposedly configured the same) it fails. I see that in the request the csrf cookie is missing.

It sends only the PHPSESSID. I have the csrf in the meta, and as hidden input. The same code is working just fine in my local configuration. And as I review for example the phpinfo it is seems with only few minor differences which do not affect this.

I am not sure if there could be any apache difference that may be of importance here. The version on my local is 2.4 and in the server is 2.2. Apart of that all else seems the same.

Comment: Atm I cannot see why the cookie is not being set. Are the other yii2 cookies being set?

Comment: show your config file

Comment: It looks like another headers (content type and php identification header) are sent before sendHeaders method is executed. For that reason it doesnt even reach the point where it should set the cookie to the response. Further investigation is pending on where and why are they sent before it

Answer (score -2):

Add following function very first in your controller :

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Or else add

```
public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

in your controller class

Hope it this will help you.If so Please mark as approved.

Comment: That just disables it and not even correctly. You should really do that in the configuration

Comment: what I want is not really disabling it.